# Creating an Elastic Search AND OR Query

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to write a query that requires "area" to be 530 and "starts" to be 06192013 OR "area" to be "530" and "starts" to be "blank". Additionally, in both of those scenarios "space" to be "top" OR "space2" to be "bottom". This query seems to be grabbing anything that matches any of these scenarios, how do I change it to make it work like I would like?

```
{
  "size":25, 
  "from":0,
  "query": {
    "custom_filters_score": {
      "query": {
        "filtered": {
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {"term":{"type":"ghost"}}, 
                {"term":{"area":"530"}}
              ]
            }
          }, 
          "filter" : {
            "or": [
              {"terms":{"space": ["top"]}}, 
              {"terms":{"space2":["bottom"]}}, 
              {
                "and": [
                  {"term":{"area":"530"}}, 
                  {"term":{"start":"06192013"}}
                ]
              }, 
              {
                "and": [
                  {"term":{"area":"530"}}, 
                  {"term":{"starts":"blank"}}
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }, 
      "filters": [
        {"filter":{"term":{"filter1":5743}}, "boost":"1000"}, 
        {"filter":{"term":{"filter2":4451}}, "boost":"64"}, 
        {"filter":{"term":{"filter3":["tech"]}}, "boost":"16"}, 
        {"filter":{"terms":{"filter4":[]}}, "boost":"8"}, 
        {"filter":{"terms":{"filter5":[]}}, "boost":"5"}, 
        {"filter":{"term":{"access":"1"}}, "boost":"2"}
      ], 
      "score_mode":"total"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there! Try this:

```
...
"query" : { "match_all":{} },
"filter" : {
    "and": [
        {
            "or": [
                {"term":{"space": "top"}}, 
                {"term":{"space2":"bottom"}}
            ]
        },
        {
            "and": [
                 {"term":{"area":"530"}}, 
                 {
                     "or": [
                         {"term":{"start":"06192013"}},
                         {"term":{"starts":"blank"}}
                     ]
                 }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
...
```

Unless you need scoring (which it doesnt look like) you should do all of this with filters, they don't calculate scores and are faster because of this.

The `"query" : { "match_all":{} }` will end up giving all docs witch match the filter the **same score**.

Note: I also turned your `terms` query with an array of one element to a `term` query...